# Hide a component clicking on another component in angular

Tags: angular, frontend

In my frontend i have three angular components: the first is a mat toggle button with two possible values: A and B, the second and the third ones are two buttons called A and B like the previous values in the mat toggle button; what I would like is that when I click on the first entry (value = A) of the mat toggle the third button (B) will be hidden and viceversa (clicking on the B choice the A button will hide).

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `ngIf` to toggle.

Comment: You can use subject behavior to achieve your objective using service.

Comment: Can you show me an example with mat buttons about the situation I've explained previously?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BehaviorSubject as it has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the BehaviorSubject.